# the docker's host machine cannot connect internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, docker, docker-network

## Question

After creating bridge network on the host machine which run docker using command:

`sudo docker network create --driver bridge hadoop`

then

- the host machine cannot connect the Internet but can connect my company local network
- the docker container can connect Internet and local network

But, if i delete the **hadoop** bridge network using command:

`sudo docker network rm hadoop`

then all is ok for the host machine network

*so can anyone help me make the host machine network restore normal when create user-definded bridge network?*

## System information

- docker version: **1.11.2**
- OS: **Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: `docker network inspect hadoop`, `netstat -nr`, and `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: thanks, the docker is ok after set dns with 8.8.8.8